# Does bootstrap have a basic circle glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Is there just a basic circle for the glyphicons in Bootstrap??? There are plenty of circles with images in them.. but I would just like to use a basic cirlce.
Thanks!

Comment: how about using the dot • character?
or these ○ ◌‬ ● ◯ ❍

Comment: Thanks QuinnFTW..I was hoping for something larger. Thanks!

Comment: Just increase the font size to like 6em

Answer (score 35):

Like others have said, the Bootstrap team have opted to not fill an icon spot with a standard character. It's pretty easy to build your own, though.

There's an empty dot, too, and, of course you can color them.

Sizing might be best accomplished by using semantic markup or by extending [Bootstrap's typography classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#type) with custom CSS.

```css
.one-fine-dot::before {
  content: "\25cf";
}

.one-fine-red-dot::before {
  content: "\25cf";
  color: red;
}

.one-fine-empty-dot::before {
  content: "\25cb";
}

.lead .one-fine-dot {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>One fine dot: <span class="glyphicon one-fine-dot"></span></p>

<p>One fine red dot: <span class="glyphicon one-fine-red-dot"></span></p>

<p>One fine empty dot: <span class="glyphicon one-fine-empty-dot"></span></p>

<p class="lead">One fine lead dot: <span class="glyphicon one-fine-dot"></span></p>

<h2>One fine heading dot: <span class="glyphicon one-fine-dot"></span></h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. There's no such icon in [the Glyphicons Halflings font](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs).

[Font Awesome has such an icon though](http://fontawesome.io/icon/circle-o/) (named `fa-circle-o`).

Answer (score 2):

not by default, you'll need to buy the commercial version of glyphicons. However, there's a better (AND FREE!) solution. Just go to [Icomoon App](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) and choose any library of your liking, you can even mix libraries and maybe even find a full circle. However, if you don't, simply upload a circle to your selected library or edit one of the existing icons.

By the way, the Icomoon Free library has a full EMPTY circle, maybe you like that, or you can edit it.

Now that you have your icons, simply export and you'll have the icons and the CSS ready to use, just like with Bootstrap